# Cannot convert from 'double' to 'double (*)'

Tags: c, matrix

I'm trying to write a code that finds inverse matrix for a given matrix. 
I keep getting the same error:

Error   5   error C2440: 'function' : cannot convert from 'double' to 'double (*)

this is my code, not sure if it works yet:

```
int swap_rows(double mat[SIZE][SIZE], int row1, int row2)
{
    int i, j, temp;
    for (j = 0; j < SIZE; i++)
    {
        temp = mat[row1][j];
        mat[row1][j] = mat[row2][j];
        mat[row2][j] = temp;
    }
    return 0;
} 

int subtract_rows(double mat[SIZE][SIZE], int row1, int row2, double mul)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        mat[row1][i] = mat[row1][i] - mul*mat[row2][i];
    }
    return 0;
}

int inverse_matrix(double mat[][SIZE], double inv[][SIZE], int size)
{
    int i, j, k, w;
    double c, b;
    for (i,j = 0; i,j < SIZE; i++)
    {
        if (mat[i][j] = 0)//cheking to see left is not zero
        { 
            for (k = i + 1; k < SIZE; k++)//if zero swap rows with one that not zero
            {
                if (mat[k][j] != 0)
                {
                    swap_rows(mat, i, k);//swap
                    swap_rows(inv, i, k);
                }
                else
                    return 0;//didnt find not zero return and exit
            }
        }
        c = mat[i][j];// c is the left number
        for (k = 0; k < SIZE; k++)
        {
            mat[i][k] /= c;//divide everyone by c, now i have one
            inv[i][k] /= c;
        }
        for (k = 0; k < SIZE; k++)
        {
            b = mat[k][j];
            if (k != i)
            {
                if (mat[k][j] > 0)
                {
                    subtract_rows(mat[SIZE][SIZE], k, i, b);// ***error points to this line***
                    subtract_rows(inv[SIZE][SIZE], k, i, b);
                }
                else
                {
                    subtract_rows(mat[SIZE][SIZE], k, i, -b);
                    subtract_rows(inv[SIZE][SIZE], k, i, -b);
                }

            }
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

can someone see where the problem is?

Answer (score 3):

`mat[SIZE][SIZE]` uses the subscript operator to index into `mat`, yielding a **`double`**.
`double mat[][SIZE]` is a **`double*[SIZE]`**, though.
Obvious mismatch.

To pass an array (which is converted to a pointer anyway) to a function, use just `mat`:

```
subtract_rows(mat, k, i, b);
```

Do that with the other `subtract_rows` calls similarly.